# Is it possible to use named function parameters in PHP?

Tags: php, named-parameters, php-8

Is it possible in `php` like in `python` to have named function parameters? An example use case is:

```
function foo($username = "", $password = "", $timeout = 10) {

}
```

I want to override `$timeout`:

```
foo("", "", 3);
```

Ugly. I would much rather do:

```
foo(timeout=3);
```